# Rotating a fitting canvas with CropperJS

Tags: javascript, matrix, rotation

**Background**

I am currently working on a cropping tool that will fit the image to the element that it is going into.  The ratio that I am getting from [cropperJS](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) is always 1:1, meaning that height == width. Once I have the x,y,height,width from cropperJS I am getting the ratio which is height/width of the element that the image is going into and adding back bits of the image to make the cropped image the same ratio as the element that it is being fit into.

**The Problem**

I am trying to make a rotating tool for my custom cropper and the X, Y data that I am getting from cropperJS is as if the image has never been rotated. I have created a function to do a matrix rotation to get the new X, Y data which I believe is working properly. My tool that rotates the canvas works fine if the image is rotated 180 but not if its 270 or 90 degrees.

**The code**

Here is the smaller function that does the calculations for the matrix rotation, where `x` and `y` are the unrotated coordinated and `xm` and `ym` are the center point of the rotation and `a` is the angle of rotation.

```
function rotate(x, y, xm, ym, a) {
    var cos = Math.cos,
        sin = Math.sin,
        a = a * Math.PI / 180, // Convert to radians
        // Subtract midpoints, so that midpoint is translated to origin
        // and add it in the end again
        xr = (x - xm) * cos(a) - (y - ym) * sin(a) + xm,
        yr = (x - xm) * sin(a) + (y - ym) * cos(a) + ym;

    return [xr, yr];
}
```

This is the function that does the cropping, it works great for angles at 0 or 180 but **does not** get the correct coordinates for **90 or 270** degrees.

```
var cropPhoto = async (imgSrc,cropData) =>{return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var img = new Image()
    var ctx, canvas
    var ratio = cropData.ratio || 1
    var h = cropData.height
    var w = cropData.width
    var x = cropData.x
    var y = cropData.y
    if ( ratio > 1 ){
        var h = ratio * cropData.height
        y = y - ( (h - cropData.height) / 2 )
    }
    else if ( ratio < 1 ){
        var w = (1 / ratio) * cropData.width
        x = x - ( (w - cropData.width) / 2 )
    }
    img.style.transform = `${cropData.rotate}deg`
    img.src = imgSrc
    img.onload = () => {
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
        canvas.height = h
        canvas.width = w
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        if(cropData.rotate != 0){
            //nv == new values
            //this only works if its 180 degrees
            var nv = rotate(x,y, cropData.image.naturalWidth/2, cropData.image.naturalHeight/2, cropData.rotate)
            x = nv[0] - w
            y = nv[1] - h
        }
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, w, h)
        canvas = cropData.rotate != 0 ? drawRotated(cropData.rotate) : canvas
        canvas.toBlob(blob => {
            try {
                var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                resolve(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob))
            } catch (error) {
                reject()
            }
        },"image/png",1)
    }
    var drawRotated = degrees => {
        var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas")
        if (  [90, 270].indexOf(Math.abs(degrees)) > -1 ){
            newCanvas.height = w
            newCanvas.width = h
        }else{
            newCanvas.height = h
            newCanvas.width = w
        }
        var ctx2 = newCanvas.getContext("2d")
        if ( [90,-270].indexOf(degrees) > -1 ){
            ctx2.translate( h  , 0 )
        }else if ( [-90,270].indexOf(degrees) > -1 ){
            ctx2.translate( 0  , w )
        }else if ( Math.abs(degrees) == 180 ){
            ctx2.translate( w , h )
        }
        ctx2.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180)
        ctx2.drawImage(canvas, 0 , 0 )
        return newCanvas
    }
})}
```

The imgSrc is a string of a URL to any standard image. An example of cropData is as follows:

```
{
    height: 221
    ratio: 0.48
    rotate: 0
    scaleX: 1
    scaleY: 1
    width: 221
    x: 695
    y: 61
}
```

I have been grinding my brain trying to figure out why the image is not getting the coordinates for 90 or 270 degrees but just cannot figure out why. I believe it has something to do with the aspect ratio of the original image, but I am not sure.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kixes/sod5x64k/)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren’t doing all these with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just want to use the output from the library and get the canvas data that way. In this case I married a little CSS and got you what you wanted.

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob()
```

This also gives you the full flexibility of the library so (as shown) you can rotate any degree and do anything else the library will let you.

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/103jh75d/10/