# Why is an image distorted when rotated 90/180deg?

Tags: javascript, cropperjs, cropper

I'am using the CropperJs library to crop and edit an image in an ionic application. I need to resize the image freely using the entire screen as cropbox, So, I had to set the crop box size equal to the width of the device and the remaining height of the container in order.

Here's the instantiation:

```
const offsetHeight = this.shapeContainer.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
const offsetWidth = this.shapeContainer.nativeElement.offsetWidth

this.cropper = new Cropper(this.image.nativeElement, {
      dragMode: "move",
      aspectRatio:  offsetWidth / offsetHeight,
      minCropBoxWidth: offsetWidth,
      minCropBoxHeight: offsetHeight,
      viewMode: 0,
      restore: false,
      guides: false,
      center: false,
      highlight: false,
      cropBoxMovable: false,
      cropBoxResizable: false,
      toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
      modal: false,
      rotatable: true,
      zoomable: true,
      
    });
```

Export in Base64 :

```
    this.cropper
        .getCroppedCanvas({
          width:  this.shapeContainer.nativeElement.offsetWidth,
          height: this.shapeContainer.nativeElement.offsetHeight,
          maxHeight: this.shapeContainer.nativeElement.offsetHeight * 4, 
          maxWidth: this.shapeContainer.nativeElement.offsetWidth * 4,
          fillColor: '#000',
          imageSmoothingQuality: 'high'
        })
        .toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container" #shapeContainer>
   <img [src]="imageBase64" #image alt="">
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

When I keep the orientation of the image as the first upload it works great. Here's an example:

[image]

The issue comes when i call

```
this.cropper.rotate(90)
```

Here's the image that I actually pushed til the edge as the previous one:

[image]

I honestly don't know what is going on. I tried everything i could, setting different aspect ratio once the rotate method gets called, changing some options passed through the Cropper class but nothing seems to work. I don't get either if this is a cropperJS bug, even though I don't quite understand why an image in a fixed container with fixed aspect ratio behaves like that.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating a fitting canvas with CropperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412219/rotating-a-fitting-canvas-with-cropperjs)

Comment: @jabaa Sorry if it was unclear. Basically, when i rotate the image using the cropper API,  the image seems to get downsized or moved. The second image, the one rotated 90deg, is the result of pushing to the edge of the container (equal to the width of the device and the remaining height) the image itself (CCSy left: 0, top: 0). But as you can see there's a gap, it should be as the first image but rotated. I thought it could be the aspect ratio but this actually refers to the cropBox which is always fixed. I never found an example with container size = cropBox size and viewMode = 0 as mine

Comment: @Yogi Unfortunately no. It's the getCroppedCanvas().toBlob() that exports the image being cut or downsized if rotated.